# Why won't my Canon EOS dRebel recognize a CF card?

Tags: cfcard

My camera (a Canon EOS Rebel XT/350D) shows error cf. I've tried all the suggestions in the manual to fix the problem. I've bought new CF cards. Nothing makes a difference. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you connect the camera to a computer via USB using Canon's *EOS Utility*?

Comment: do you have a card reader ?  does the cards disc image mount when you put the card in the reader and connect it to you computer ?  can you extract any files on the card and erase the card.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you have a broken/bent pin in the CF card slot.  Given that the Rebel XT/350D was introduced in 2005, and that any copy you have is liable to be well over a decade old. That's *really* old in dSLR terms. And that CF card slot has a lot of small delicate pins in them that can easily be damaged by carelessly jamming something into the slot, or even simply mis-seating the card.

I'd suggest inspecting the slot with a flashlight to determine whether or not there's any physical damage. If there is, then it's probably time to consider getting a new camera, as servicing the camera is likely to cost far more than the camera is worth, given that a service call to Canon tends to flat rate around US$300, and a used XT goes for less than US$150 these days.

Comment: I still have one of these (as a spare which I keep in work) , and I take chances with it that I wouldn't with something that still had value. So if *I* spotted a bent pin I'd try to get in and fix it. I might even open it up if I couldn't see a bent pin, in the basis of nothing to lose.

Comment: @ChrisH A bent pin, yeah. A broken or *damaged* pin, not so much. And everybody's tolerance for tiny screws is different.

Comment: Luckily I've never damaged a pin in the camera, but I've bent a few in card readers etc. and never broken one off. I'd even try fitting a new connector if I could get one cheap (though I'd use that as an excuse to upgrade my soldering kit)

Comment: A credit card cut lengthwise to make it thin enough will fit into the slot and between the rows of pins. I've repaired a handful of CF point and shoots that way (tells you how long ago it was.) The tool goes on the outside of either row and in the middle. I start with where the bent pin is facing then among the other spaces, "massaging" the pins straight. If the pin is bent too far over you'll need to open the camera. In one extreme case I actually broke the pin out of the camera and jammed a bit of wire into the opposite hole on the card. This is very much a bad idea but it saved the shoot.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the card from its place inside the camera. Using my household vacuum hose I ran it across the holes of the card. I put the card back in the slot, turned the camera on and it continues to work as if it was new. It's worth a try at this point. Too expensive to have my local camera shop look at it with a $100 base look at it bench charge.